# BibTeX style for the American Society for Microbiology (ASM) – chronological order, authors bold

Tags: bibtex, formatting, sorting

I am trying to format a bibliography for the ASM journals. 
I found development.bst, which is similar to the ASM format, but this journal puts the references in alphabetical order and I want the journal entries given numbers based on chronological order of appearance in the manuscript. Is there a way for me to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: AMS provides their own bibliography styles: `amsalpha`, `amsplain` http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/misc

Comment: I need formatting for ASM, not AMS - it's the american society for microbiology. I need the bibliography to be in chronological order with the authors name in bold. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Sorry. AMS is nearly ASM ;-). You can try `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`

Comment: How do I use that with development.bst? It seems not to be reading unsrt.bst

Comment: I don't know `development.bst`. The style `unsrt` is a replacement of `development`. It fits your sorting needs.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at biblatex, loading it with the option sorting=none. That will do the job for the entries numbered in the order they appear in your text. One of the main advantages is that it is much easier to modify a bibliography style of biblatex than a .bst style file, as it uses a latex-type syntax.

Then choose a style of bibliography as close as possible to the ASM style. If the author's name formatting isn't in boldface, you should modify its formatting. For this task, you should probably write in your preamble something like:

```
  \DeclareNameFormat{author}{\bfseries%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}
  {#1%
  123
  \ifblank{#3}{}{\addcomma\space #3}}
  {\ifblank{#3}{}{#3\space}%
  #1}%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}
  {\addcomma\space}
  {}}
```

This is only an example from the doc of biblatex. You should find the exact \DeclareNameFormat{author}{...} command for the style you want to use and add the \bfseries switching command.